# How to read a filename with special characters from disk into a FileField?

Tags: python, django

In my Django app, I am downloading a Youtube video to some folder inside `MEDIA_ROOT`.

I am also associating the downloaded file with a model's `FileField` under the video title.

The problem occurs when the video title contains some special characters. For example "Idiot Test - 90% fail" will be saved to disk with `%` removed, so when associating this file by video title to a model I will get an error that such file does not exist, because I am passing the original video title (not the one read from disk) to the `FileField` which contains the `%`.

How can I solve this? Should I strip the video title of any special characters first? But then I would need to cater for what is allowed on different OSes. Is there a better solution?

```
downloaded_path = pytube.download(sampler_settings.AUDIO_PATH, video_title)
downloaded = File(open(downloaded_path, 'rb'))

# create folder by the name of current session key where the downloaded file will be stored
session_folder = os.path.join(sampler_settings.AUDIO_PATH, session_key)
os.mkdir(session_folder)

main_sample = MainSample()
main_sample.session_key = session_key
main_sample.audio = os.path.join(session_folder, video_title)
main_sample.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at Regular Expressions

The solution would be something like:

```
import re
video_title = re.escape(video_title)
downloaded_path = pytube.download(sampler_settings.AUDIO_PATH, video_title)
downloaded = File(open(downloaded_path, 'rb'))
...
```

Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Let me know if this works for you :)